# Grid visibility when getting back to the main window

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a main window that contains a stack Panel containing some buttons. To each button I have an associated grid panel which in turn has several image buttons.  clicking a grid panel image button opens a new window . On the main window my grid visibility is set to Hidden(because I want the grid to be displayed only when one of the buttons is clicked from the stack panel)but when I click the back button on the new window, I want the  selected grid to be visible .How to achieve this? I am not using MVVM .

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Custom="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/ribbon" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WpfApplication5.Window1"
    Title="Home_window" Height="456.163" Width="653.173" Background="#FF9CB5D3">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="buttonicon" UriSource="/Images/icon.png"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>



    <Grid x:Name="menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="131" Margin="1,156,0,-211" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123">

        <StackPanel x:Name="menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Margin="13,30,-13,-49">
            <Button Content="Home" Height="25" Click="Button_Click_1" >
                <Button.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF3CABEA"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.322"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF62A7CF" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="b" Height="25"  Click="Button_Click_8">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF3CABEA" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.322"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF62A7CF" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="c" Height="25"  Click="Button_Click_9">
                <Button.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF3CABEA" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.322"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF62A7CF" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>

            <Button Content="d" Height="25"  Click="Button_Click_10">
                <Button.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF3CABEA" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.322"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF62A7CF" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="e" Height="25" Click="Button_Click_11">
                <Button.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF3CABEA" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.322"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF62A7CF" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>

     </StackPanel>

    </Grid>



    <Grid x:Name="grid_home" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="260" Margin="167,156,-123,-105" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="445" Background="#FF577EAC" Visibility="Hidden">
        <Button Margin="35,29,305,160" Click="Button_Click_2">
            <StackPanel x:Name="inventory" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="66">
                <Image Source="images/inventory.png" Stretch ="Uniform" Width="35" RenderTransformOrigin="1.343,-0.22" Margin="0,12,0,10"/>

                <TextBlock Text="  Inventory" FontSize="12" Width="67" Height="19" Margin="0,24,0,23"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>

        <Button Margin="167,29,173,160" Click="Button_Click_3" >
            <StackPanel x:Name="supplier" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="66">
                <Image Source="images/supplier.jpg" Stretch ="Uniform" Width="35" RenderTransformOrigin="1.343,-0.22" Margin="0,12,0,10"/>

                <TextBlock Text="  Supplier" FontSize="12" Width="67" Height="19" Margin="0,24,0,23"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button Margin="302,29,38,160" Click="Button_Click_4">
            <StackPanel x:Name="purchase order" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="66">
                <Image Source="images/po.jpg" Stretch ="Uniform" Width="35" RenderTransformOrigin="1.343,-0.22" Margin="0,9,0,13"/>

                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Width="68" Margin="0,17,0,15"><Run Text="  Purchase"/><LineBreak/><Run Text="     Order"/></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button Margin="35,141,305,49" Click="Button_Click_5">
            <StackPanel  x:Name="shipping" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="66" Width="101">
                <Image Source="images/shipping.png" Stretch ="Uniform" Width="35" RenderTransformOrigin="1.343,-0.22" Margin="0,6,0,16"/>

                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Width="68" Margin="0,17"><Run Text=" Shipping "/></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>

        </Button>

        <Button  Margin="166,142,174,48" Click="Button_Click_6" >
            <StackPanel x:Name="sales" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="66">
                <Image Source="images/sales.jpg
                       " Stretch ="Uniform" Width="35" RenderTransformOrigin="1.343,-0.22" Margin="0,7,0,15"/>

                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Width="68" Margin="0,20,0,14" Text="    Sales "/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button Margin="303,143,38,47" Click="Button_Click_7" >
            <StackPanel x:Name="purchase report" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="66">
                <Image Source="images/pr.jpg" Stretch ="Uniform" Width="35" RenderTransformOrigin="1.343,-0.22" Margin="0,8,0,14"/>

                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Width="68" Margin="0,14,0,17"><Run Text=" Purchase "/><LineBreak/><Run Text="  Reports"/></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>

    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="grid_b" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="260" Margin="167,156,-123,-105" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="445" Background="#FFB5CDEA" Visibility="Hidden">
    </Grid>
```

On selecting Home option it displays grid_home. On grid_home on clicking inventory button it opens inventory window:

```
  <Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.inventory"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Inventory" Height="300" Width="469.611">
<Grid Margin="0,0,2,0">
    <Button Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="195,223,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="37" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
```

part of codebehind for home window:

```
   private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        grid_home.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        grid_b.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    }

    private void Button_Click_8(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        inventory obj = new inventory();
        obj.Show();
        this.Close();

    }
```

---

part of  code behind for inventory window:

```
     private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Home_window obj = new Home_window();
        obj.Show();
        this.Close();
        grid_home.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please post your XAML and C# code you done so far?

Comment: I get confused which grid is grid you saying, please name yours grids, stackpanels and use theirs names, so we can understand your more clearly

Comment: There's no `Grid_2` in your example, and no 'back button'. You have two `Button_Click_1` handlers with no indication on where they are located. You need to remove all the fluff (brushes) and add more related code (what's Window1 and Window2?)

Comment: On the home window visibility of the grid_home is set hidden and is only visible when I click the home button. Now once the home button is clicked it shows the grid_home . From the grid I select button inventory to open the inventory window. Now on clicking the back button I want the Home window to display the grid_home (that is the parent grid of inventory button without having to click the home button. is it possible ..